# PHP and Mysql error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version"

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to code a little log thing for my Home automations script but then I got this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

My SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO
    logsa (timeb, msg, actionb)
VALUES 
    ('12-05-2018 02:29:38pm',
    'Succesfully send a trigger to https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/test/with/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx With name test',
    'https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/test/with/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

and my code is:

```
    $logmsg = ("Succesfully send a trigger to " . $row["actiona"] . " With name " . $row["namea"]);

    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");

    $date = date("d-m-Y");
    $time = date("h:i:sa");
    $fulldate = ($date . " " . $time);

    $actiona = $row["actiona"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO logsa (timeb, msg, actionb)
    VALUES ('$fulldate', '$logmsg', '$actiona'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Comment: You don't close your parenthesis in your query (could just be a copy paste error to the question here)

Comment: Is this `'12-05-2018 02:29:38pm'` a valid datetime in mariaDB?

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Thank you James I did just not notice that.

Comment: brackets not closing properlly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice RiggsFolly. I am totally new to this.

Comment: What data type have you defined `timeb` as in your database schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `timeb` data value `$fulldate` to use a valid date time format like this

```
$fulldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

MySQL and mariaDB expect DATETIME columns to be stored in a very specific format and yours was invalid.

Also you should be using prepared and parametrised queries [[link]](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) to avoid SQL Injection attacks like this

```
$logmsg = ("Succesfully send a trigger to " . 
            $row["actiona"] . 
            " With name " . 
            $row["namea"]);

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");

$fulldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$actiona = $row["actiona"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO logsa (timeb, msg, actionb) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param('sss', $fulldate, $logmsg, $actiona );
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ($result) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: No problem RiggsFolly. But thanks guys for all your help.